# How do I resolve Cookies problem in JQuery

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to use cookies for my Web site.
I saw some examples like this one :
https://jsfiddle.net/donejs/wMN7G/
but I have the following error:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#84:28'>84:28</a> Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function"
```

After reading the solutions of this problem, I understood that this syntax : $.cookie is no more used. So I have tried to use this : `Cookies.get('name')` but it didn't work. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: Where is your code? Where do the error happen?  If it's in Javascript check your example, the syntax is `document.cookie`

Comment: the code is on this link : https://jsfiddle.net/donejs/wMN7G/

Comment: That `jsfiddle` doesn't work either and throws the same error in the dev tools console.
What's the end goal here? Or what's the question?